# ¿Cómo almacenar la fecha y hora actual en tiempo real en una variable string en Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, java-ee, spring-mvc

Este método lo tengo en una clase que llamé "DateTimeSuite"

```
static SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
static long miliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
static java.sql.Date date = new Date(miliseconds);
public static String dateFormateada = formato.format(date);
```

Lo que hago es traerme el valor del String "**dateFormateada**" de la siguiente manera:

String **dateFormateada**=DateTimeSuite.dateFormateada;

Para almacenarlo en los distintos módulos (otras clases de mi proyecto java), el problema es que me trae siempre la misma fecha y hora en la que levanté el proyecto...
Lo que necesito es que almacene la fecha y hora con minutos y segundos actualizados en cada operación... de modo tal que cada vez que yo llame a la variable **dateFormateada** tenga un nuevo valor.

Comment: ¿No puedes simplemente guardar la fecha en un `Date` y luego mostrarla como corresponda? Por cierto, más simple puedes usar `new Date()`

Answer (score 0):

Ya conseguí la respuesta a mi pregunta... la solución consistía en convertir en método la variable, para de esta manera el método traería un nuevo valor con fecha y hora cada vez que se invoque.

```
public String fecha()
{
    SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm aa");
    long miliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
    java.sql.Date date = new Date(miliseconds);
    String dateFormateada = formato.format(date);
    return dateFormateada;
}
```

Y lo llamo de esta manera:

```
DateTimeSuite fechax = new DateTimeSuite();
fechax.fecha()
```